# Microsoft WebHelpers with NETCore.App (2.1)

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to get the below code to work, but I keep getting compatibility problems with Microsoft.Web.Helpers v 3.2.6 and my current SDK package of NETCore 2.1.  Also, for the life of me, I can't get the simplest calls of IsPost and Request to be recognized.  I'm sure it's an obvious fix, but I can't find it!

Thanks in Advance for any direction...

```
@using Microsoft.Web.Helpers;
@{
    var fileName = "";
    if (IsPost) {
        var fileSavePath = "";
        var uploadedFile = Request.Files[0];
        fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
        fileSavePath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/UploadedFiles/" +
          fileName);
        uploadedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
    }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>FileUpload - Single-File Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>FileUpload - Single-File Example</h1>
    @FileUpload.GetHtml(
        initialNumberOfFiles:1,
        allowMoreFilesToBeAdded:false,
        includeFormTag:true,
        uploadText:"Upload")
    @if (IsPost) {
        <span>File uploaded!</span><br/>
    }
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WebHelpers library is not compatible with ASP.NET Core. It relies on System.Web, which .NET Core has been designed to move away from.

The replacement for the `IsPost` block is a [handler method](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods). By convention, a handler method named `OnPost` will be executed if the method used to request the page is `POST` (which is what the `IsPost` property used to check).

Personally, I never understood the point of the FileUpload helper unless you wanted to allow the user to add additional file uploads to the page (which you clearly don't in this case). An `input type="file"` is easier to add to a page.

File uploading in ASP.NET Core is completely different to Web Pages. Here's some guidance on it: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/file-upload